# Matching backslash with regex in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, regular-expression, replace

I'm attempting to remove a part of string in an attribute column of a shapefile. The part in question is `Snapshots\\` from `Snapshots\390_measure_1.jpeg`. So I want the output to be `390_measure_1.jpeg`.

Right now I'm using the Field Calculator like so to do this:

```
regexp_replace("Snapshot_1", '([a-zA-Z])+\\ ([0-9])+_([a-zA-Z])+\.([a-zA-Z])+', '\\2\\3')
```

This however does nothing to the output. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.
Also there seems to be no way to escape `\\` (The backslash character) in order to match it separately.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by `escape "" (The backslash character) in order to match it seperately`? backslash is part of the string? You want to keep backslashes or not?

Comment: I wanted to remove the backslash, so I needed to escape it in regex in order for regex to match it. If I didn't escape it, regex wouldn't realise that it's a part of the string, rather than a part of regex syntax. Sorry for confusing terminology, I'm not a programmer or a native speaker of English.

Comment: Yes, as you found out, two backslashes \\ are used in QGIS expression engine regex to mask characters

Comment: This question is clearly addressed in the [12.2.24.12. regexp_replace - QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-replace):  "Backslash characters must be double escaped."  Since the normal regex for a literal backslash is '\\' and backslash characters need to be double escaped in QGIS regexp functions, you end up with '\\\\'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do this seems to be

```
regexp_replace("Snapshot_1",'Snapshots\\\\','')
```

This removes "Snapshots\" from the regex as it somehow escapes the backslash.

Answer (score 4):

You could just split on the \ character and return the last element of the array:

```
split( "Snapshots_1", '\\', -1)
```

[image]

The custom split function can be defined in the Function Editor:

[image]

```
from qgis.core import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def split(value, char, index, feature, parent):
    """
    Splits the parameter on char and returns split[index].
    <h2>Example usage:</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>split("a_b", "_", 0) -> a</li>
      <li>split("a b c", " ", 1) -> b</li>
    </ul>
    """
    return value.split(char)[index]
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not provide an answer as split function is a custom function, not predifined (maybe you defined it earlier, so it already existist). You should provide the code to create the split function, otherwise this solution does not work.

Comment: @Babel, I've never defined it, but have included the code.

Answer (score 3):

Two other options how to do it: one without, the other with Regular Expressions.

1. Without using regular expressions:

   ```
   replace (
       "Snapshot_1",
       left ("Snapshot_1",10),
       ''
   )
   ```

   This looks for the 10 characters at the left (first 10 characters, line 3) of the input string (line 2) and replaces them with an empty string (line 4).

   *If `\` (backslash character) is part of the input string, replace 10 with 11 in the expression.*

---

2. With regular expressions

   ```
   substr( 
       "Snapshot_1",
       regexp_match( 
           "Snapshot_1",
           '\\\\'
       )+1
   )
   ```

   This looks for the position of the first backslash `\` and returns the substring based on the input starting with the next character: from the first character after the `\` till the end.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use substr() and strpos().
strpos(string, char) returns the position of the first match for char in the string.
substr(string, start[, optional length]) returns the part of the string starting at position start and an optional length, which isn't needed here.

Position of the first backslash: `strpos(Snapshot_1, '\\')`

Part of the string starting after the backslash. (Note: we need to add 1 position to set the start after the backslash.)
`substr(Snapshot_1, strpos(Snapshot_1, '\\')+1)`